# Upgrading from 18.04.5 to a newer edition

Tags: apt, software-sources

After trying to update my current edition through the terminal, I get these results among others:

```
Ign:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease
Err:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates Release 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Comment: If you're using 18.04.5, why do your pastes have lines from 17.10?   Artful is EOL & upgraded to 18.04 itself.  Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Standard releases have a supported life of 9 months, a LTS or *long-term-support* release has a supported life of 5 years (extended via use of ESM longer but off-topic on this site, but note flavors only offer 3 years for LTS).  Your 2019-October (*artful*) release (19.10 using the *yy.mm* format of Ubuntu releases) is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus software repository has moved to old-releases. You should have *release-upgraded* when prompted before it reached EOL (see EOLUpgrades in prior comment)

Comment: If in fact you are (or at least believe you're) running 18.04/bionic, leaving in the proof of that would have changed perception; as your pastes only show off-topic ARTFUL or 17.10 detail, which gives errors because it's EOL. The counters imply there is more than we're seeing, but we're limited to the detail you provide; your paste not matching up with your limited description. With more detail, we can understand more & provide more helpful advice.